# Como retornar una string con mayusculas?

Tags: javascript

estoy intentado hacer una función que al pasarle ciertos argumentos(números que actuaran como índices), con esos números cambiará los índices de una string(que transformo en array) a MAYÚSCULAS, pero no me devuelve nada..

Segunda explicacion:

***Una string la transformé en array para trabajar con sus índices y luego los argumentos enviados, se usaran para especificar los índices y así estos indíces del array de la STRING, transformarlos a mayúsculas y luego devolverlos como una string con el método join, y con las mayúsculas aplicadas –***

```js
function f() { // Funcion
  
  var a = "hola"; // Variable
  var e = a.split(''); // Transformo en array
  var args = arguments.length; // Cantidad de argumentos
  var i = 0; // Contador para el for
  var finals = ""; // Variable para retornar string modificada
  
  var maximo = Math.max.apply(null, arguments); // el argumento mas alto
  
  for(;i<args;i++){ // recorro los argumentos
     
    
    if(arguments[i] > e.length -1) { // Si algun argumento es mayor que los elementos del string, retorna undefined
      
      finals = undefined; // undefined
      
    }
    else if(arguments[i] == e[i]) { // si el argumento recorrido es igual a algun indice de la string, por ejemplo ingresó como argumento 2 y cuando e[i] sea igual a e[2](mismo numero que el argumento) , la letra del string(que se transformó en array) sera modificada a MAYÚSCULA, y luego se le sumará el resto de la string con slice, desde el máximo de los argumentos(osea slice(comienzo,final))
      
      finals += e[i].toUpperCase() + e.slice(maximo,e.length);
      
    }
    
    
  }
  
   return finals;   // vuelvo a meter la string que habia sido convertida en array, a un string con join()
  
  
  
}

var a = f(2);

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Osea, quieres convertir los elementos de un array a mayuscula?

Comment: Una string la transformé en array para trabajar con sus índices y luego los argumentos enviados, se usaran para especificar los índices y así estos indíces del array de la STRING, transformarlos a mayúsculas y luego devolverlos como una string con el método join, y con las mayúsculas aplicadas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Pasando a mayúscula los señalados

No sé si interpreto lo que necesitas. Pero quizás esto te ayude a avanzar

```js
function f() { // Funcion
  
  var a = "hola"; // Variable
  var e = a.split(''); // Transformo en array
  var args = arguments.length; // Cantidad de argumentos
  var finals = e; // Variable para retornar arranca como array "e"
  
  for(var i = 0;i<args;i++){ // recorro los argumentos
    var pos=arguments[i];
    if(pos>=0 && pos< e.length) {
      finals[pos] = e[pos].toUpperCase();
    }else{
      return undefined
    }
  }
  return finals.join('');
}

console.log('hoLa=',f(2));
console.log('hOlA=',f(1,3));
```

Comment: vaya.. no era tan dificil como pensaba, gracias capo !