# Retornar Array en mayusculas

Tags: javascript

Si tengo:

```js
        var e = "String";
        var f = e.split('');  
        var d = f;
        d += f[2].toUpperCase(); 

       /*   d + = f[2].toUpperCase().split(''); *///Segundo intento


    
    console.log(d.join(''));
```

Como puedo retornar el string como 'StRing' y no como 'StringR' ?

y segundo, porque el metodo `join()`, no funciona correctamente?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que join no funciona correctamente?

Comment: @Rubén me da error lo puse en snippet, ya me dijeron el error, pero nose como solucionarlo ya intente algo..

Comment: No porque te da error deberías decir que no funciona correctamente.

Comment: @EduardoSebastian, ya vi esta pregunta de tu parte con una ligera modificacion en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/85728/como-retornar-una-string-con-mayusculas (Duplicado sin dudas)

Comment: @NekoOs: Reportala como duplicado.

Comment: No se como la verdad, deja e investigo

Comment: @NekoOs: Haz clic en el enlace reportar y luego selecciona es un duplicado

Comment: Gracias @Rubén me sirve para colaborar un poco con los moderadores, ya estaba a punto de tomarme el tiempo de leer información en los meta. -- Reportado como duplicado

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61843/discussion-between-ruben-and-nekoos).

Answer (score 1):

El código en la pregunta tiene varios problemas.

Por un lado se asigna un valor a d, pero luego inmediatamente después se asigna otro valor. El segundo valor asignado a d es un cadena de longitud uno, y join devuelve error porque es un método de `Array`, no de `String`

Otro problema es que se utiliza la palabra `string` siendo que no es recomendable usar palabras clave ni como valores de variable ni como nombres de variable porque esto conduce a confusiones.

En el siguiente ejemplo, para evitar confusiones en lugar de `string` como valor se está usando `montaña`.

Nótese que se utilizan sólo dos variables, `a` y `b`.

```js
var a = "montaña";
var b = a.split('');
b[2] = b[2].toUpperCase();
console.log(b.join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Contesto en el código. Básicamente el problema es que si a es un Array a+'x' es un string (el + primero convierte el array en string metiéndole comas en el medio).

```js
    var e = "String"; 
    console.log('e',e,typeof e);
    var f = e.split('');  
    console.log('f',f,typeof f, f.constructor.name);
    var d = f;
    d += f[2].toUpperCase();
    // acá d se convirtió de nuevo en un string (por el +=) y luego se le agregó una letra al final en mayúsculas
    console.log('d',d,typeof d, d.constructor.name);
    
    // lo siguiente falla porque de es un String y los Strings no tienen join
    console.log(d.join(''));
```

Comment: mm intenté volviendolo a transformar a un array y luego join, pero igual, que podría hacer entonces?

Comment: @Rubén, ya sé que devuelve error. Estaba contestando la segunda pregunta. Es cierto. Me faltó la primera

Comment: @Rubén. La primer pregunta ya se la había contestado al usuario en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/85728/como-retornar-una-string-con-mayusculas/85735#85735 Por eso creo que lo importante es darle herramientas para que entienda por qué le está pasando lo que le está pasando.

Comment: @EmilioPlatzer: Cada pregunta y respuesta deben ser autocontenidas, incluso las de seguimiento. Si el OP está repitiendo una pregunta debería ser marcada como duplicado, por otro lado, cada pregunta debería contener´sólo una pregunta.

Comment: @Rubén, entiendo tu opinión y en parte la comparto. Se trata de dejar fluir. Algunas preguntas basadas en opiniones son muy buenas (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/82254/se-deber%C3%ADa-usar-jquery-en-toda-aplicaci%C3%B3n-html-css-javascript). Otras preguntas mal formuladas reciben la suficiente atención para ayudar al que pregunta. Si es positivo y todos nos tratamos bien se puede ser un poco flexible con las reglas.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61866/discussion-between-ruben-and-emilio-platzer).